# BeautifulSoup extract div text without div in it

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a little bit of difficulty extracting text from a div that has div inside (without it). So here it is:

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div class="status_p">
    ACTIVE
    </div>
   Name
</div>
```

I want to extract Name without div that has ACTIVE. Whenever I print first div, it always gives me ACTIVEName

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children` attribute on bs4 tag that gives you all the children in a tag. After choosing children, you can get the last element of the children list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div style="width:100%">
    <div class="status_p">
    ACTIVE
    </div>
   Name
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(list(soup.find("div").children)[-1].strip())
```

Output:

```
Name
```

OR

you can use `stripped_strings`

```
print(list(soup.find("div").stripped_strings)[-1])
```

OR

you can delete the inner div and get only the name.

```
soup.find("div",class_="status_p").extract()
print(soup.find("div").get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: I get error everytime I try to use .children or .stripped_strings

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution and used

```
find("div", class_="status_p").decompose()
```